# Capture video to canvas flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video-capture

I would like to implement a video to canvas app like my example in js : http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9kfwot/2/

But my problem is how i can take a screenshot of video player in a specific area?
like js in drawImage:

```
ctx.drawImage(sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height); // js drawimage
```

but in Flutter what can i use for reproduce video to canvas?

i created a simple flutter project with a video player:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: YoYoPlayer(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        url:
            "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv",
        videoStyle: VideoStyle(),
        videoLoadingStyle: VideoLoadingStyle(
          loading: Center(
            child: Text("Loading video"),
            //capture image of video and display it
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

[RenderRepaintBoundary](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary-class.html) and drawImage is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, RenderRepaintBoundary and drawImage is what you want.

```dart
  GlobalKey _repaintKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: RenderRepaintBoundary(
        key: _repaintKey,
        child: YoYoPlayer(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          url:
              "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv",
          videoStyle: VideoStyle(),
          videoLoadingStyle: VideoLoadingStyle(
            loading: Center(
              child: Text("Loading video"),
              //capture image of video and display it
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

```dart
final boundary = _repaintKey.context.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
final image = await boundary.toImage();
canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(10, 20), paint);
```

Comment: Thank you @uanirudhx, in the second part canvas.drawImage need offset but how i can specify a custom position like (sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height) ? did you have a example please?

Comment: I've added an example to draw at a custom offset, but you will have to resize the image some other way. However you might have been looking for the [drawImageRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImageRect.html) method.